# Is Vouchering a valid synonym for "time booking" or not?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, gerunds

I have an ongoing dispute with someone who insists on using "Vouchering" in official documents as a synonym for "time booking" - (as in making entries on a time management system against booking numbers).

As the on-line OED returns "No such word in the English Language!" I feel that we should not be using it but thought I would ask here if there is any evidence that this is a valid usage.

Almost all the on-line resources that I have found that mention the word consider it a valid word for Scrabble but I can find no mention of it in the context of time booking.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vouchering --

Comment: Apparently, the use of *vouchering* for "time booking" is a domain specific usage, in the Travel & Tourism industry and possibly in HR. *... to manage daily time and attendance for two shift systems plus job hours vouchering.*

Comment: I'm not a huge believer in using dictionaries, even the OED, as the one true ultimate authority on what is or isn't a word. They are *descriptive*, not *prescriptive*.

Comment: @T.E.D. well, some are prescriptive, but they are intended for use by children and other learners, so they tend not to cover a particularly large lexicon.

Comment: Still, the idea that any branch of the OED would say something as prescriptive as "No such word in the English Language" is a shocking idea, even without the strange choice of capitalisation.

Comment: Sorry - the inaccurate quote was mine the exact response was "No exact results found for Vouchering in the dictionaries."

Answer (score 1):

A *voucher* is a document or token that serves as a bearer instrument proving some right.

Such a voucher could be a physical thing, or a digital record, though it would be stretching the word quite a bit if it wasn't the person claiming the right who possessed the digital record. E.g. if I receive an e-mail upon booking a cinema seat, then that is a voucher, but if the only record is held at the cinema, then that is not a voucher.

If your time-booking system uses such vouchers, whether physical or digital, then both maintaining the system, and issuing individual vouchers (as part of booking time) would be *vouchering*.

Now, from this, if people were used to calling it *vouchering* then they would end up using the term even if using a system with no such vouchers. And it would still be a reasonable use of the term, comparable to calling a truck driver a *teamster* in American English, even if he's never actually driven a team of horses in his life, and so on.

Whether it would be an advisable term to use is another matter. There is at least one person who doesn't get why it's called *vouchering* (you). If the system involves issuing vouchers (e.g. sending e-mails) then I'd say your colleague is in the right, and you should just concede that since vouchering is an integral part of booking time, it's a reasonable name for the task. If however there are no such vouchers, then I would suggest that while it may be an arguably valid name, it may not be one that will be clear to everyone, and "booking time" would serve better.

(From the perspective of euphony or general lingual conservatism, I can see some objecting to "vouchering" but then "time-booking" is hardly an improvement, is it. If your objection is along those lines, use "booking time").

Comment: The process involves the user filling in an on-line time sheet - no tokens of any kind are exchanged.  The act is that of recording, i.e. the bookkeeping, of time spent on projects.  Booking time is usually used in the sense of making an advanced reservation where as this is entering time spent into the books.  A quick survey of my other colleges shows that most of them deleted the email titled Changes to Vouchering Procedure without opening the attached document on the grounds that since they didn't know/care what Vouchering was it was nothing to do with them.

Comment: Then I'd say it's valid for the reasons I gave (some systems do use vouchers, hence leading to the process being called that) but inadvisable.

Answer (score 0):

In the "dictionary" that I carry in my head *voucher* is a noun and a voucher has an intrinsic value; however, other other, published, dictionaries consider it as both.  OED cites the ME *vouch*, a verb, as an early form.  Other dictionaries cite an old French verb, *voucher*, are go all the way back into Latin to *vocare*, to call or to speak.  A foreign verb that ends in *-er* is at risk of becoming a noun in English because of the ending.  There has been so much talk in recent years in AE of "school vouchers" that the word sounds like a noun to my ear (and perhaps to the questioner's ear as well), but when *voucher* is a verb, I don't think we can but admit that *vouchering* is a valid verb-base +ing form.

Comment: Surely - in that context a voucher would be one who vouches?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a few people who use the word "vouchering". However, the word wasn't meant to share the same meaning as time booking. I believe they used it entirely for another meaning; from what I could understand on what they were trying to imply.